# Using for loop in angular with $scopes

Tags: angularjs, for-loop

Is it possible to made a for loop using scopes in angular? For example. I have:

```
$scope.start = 1;
$scope.end = 10;
```

and want to make a for (example i know it doesn't work)

```
for($scope.start; $scope.start < $scope.end; $scope.start++) {
   print(<input type="radio" name="count" value="$scope.start">);
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run that loop?  Replace your print statement with something which is more logical, like a simple console.log("test")

Comment: A for loop is just plain old JavaScript and theres nothing special about using scopes here.  Are you looking for ng-repeat?

Comment: i have hours from 8:00 to 20:00 and i have them in database, i want to do loop from 8:00 to 20:00, increase by 30mins is it possible with ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.start = '8:00';
    $scope.stop = '20:00';
    $scope.interval = '30';
    
    $scope.getTimeArray = function(start, stop, interval){
      var result = [];
      if(interval == '0')
        return result;
    
      function toMinutes(time){
        var pair = time.split(':');
        return pair[0] * 60 + 1 * pair[1];
      }
      function toString(minutes){
        var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        var min = (minutes - hours * 60);
        min = min > 9 ? min : '0' + min;
        return hours + ':' + min;
      }
            
      for(var i = toMinutes(start); i <= toMinutes(stop); i += 1 * interval)
        result.push(toString(i)) 
        
      return result;
    }      
}])
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyController">
    start: <input type="text" ng-model='start'>
    </br>
    stop: <input type="text" ng-model='stop'>
    </br>
    interval: <input type="text" ng-model='interval'>
    </br>
    <label ng-repeat-start='item in getTimeArray(start, stop, interval)'>{{item}}</label>
    <input type="radio" name="count" value="{{item}}" ng-repeat-end>
</div>
```

Comment: Thansk a lot! Works great!